# How is this parameter changing its value?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
        int temp;
        res = int.TryParse(discountTextBox.Text, out temp);

        if (res == false)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter Discount in integers", "Error");

            return;
        }
        double Discount = (double) temp;
        if (!transactiondao.ValidateDiscount(curremployee, Discount, retail))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Discount entered", "error");
            return;
        }
```

Above block of code calls the method below. However, while debugging discount has the value that user specified. After the if block is executed however, it changes to 0.

```
public bool ValidateDiscount(Employee emp, double GivenDiscount, int retailprice)
    {
        bool res = false;
        double sMaxDiscount = emp.GetAuthorizedMaxDiscount();

        //validating against retail price
        double rMaxDiscount;
        if (retailprice == 2000)
            rMaxDiscount = 4;
        else if (retailprice == 3000)
            rMaxDiscount = 5;
        else if (retailprice == 4000)
            rMaxDiscount = 8;
        else
            rMaxDiscount = -1;

        double MaxDiscount;
        if (sMaxDiscount >= rMaxDiscount)
            MaxDiscount = sMaxDiscount;
        else
            MaxDiscount = rMaxDiscount;

        if (GivenDiscount < MaxDiscount)
        {
            res = true;
        }

        return res;
    }
```

here is the call to ValidateDiscount. commenting out the if block and thus bypassing validatediscount works perfectly and discount retains the value entered by user. How does this happen?

Comment: One thing (probably not solving your case though) would be to use `Double.TryParse()` instead of using int and then explicitly casting it to double.

Comment: @KamilT doesnt work. the out variable is of type int.

Comment: `temp` should be a `double` too. Check the answer below from abdul.

Comment: @Marcus, is the code listing you've provided complete? Are you sure that the `Discount` variable isn't modified anywhere else after the validation happens?

Comment: yes. the whole block of code resides where i am taking input from windows form. This is the only part where discount is being used. Later on it is passed on as a parameter to a constructor call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `temp` as an `int`, later you cast `temp` as a double. This won't give the desired result. Try this.

```
double temp;
res = double.TryParse(discountTextBox.Text, out temp);
```

Comment: I understand the logic there, but why should a cast from int to double cause problems? Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: `int.TryParse` is failing when you pass a double value, thats the reason you get `0` as result. If you check the boolean value returned by `TryParse` it is `False`.

Comment: in that case shouldnt the messagebox pop up? Because they arent. the program runs with discount always remaining 0. Also, I implemented it like that because i need users to enter integers.

Comment: @Marcus, did this solve your problem in the end? You are right, that the message box should pop-up.

Comment: Messagebox didn't pop because you declared `int temp` and also used `int.TryParse` previously, and this wont give you a double result as you need. You can use 0 as discount with double, if you pass a double value to int.TryParse, it will fail. But if you pass an int to double.TryParse, it wont fail.

Comment: I passed values like 2 and 4. pretty sure they should work with `int.TryParse`. They stay the same values until the if block is executed. That's my real question. I commented out the if block and everything is working fine. Why does that happen? 
@botond.botos Yup this did solve my problem, however.

Comment: @Marcus, you even tried to debug the code and you saw that after invoking the `ValidateDiscount` method the value of the `Discount` variable has changed to 0?

Comment: @botond.botos Exactly!

Comment: Do not mix integers and doubles, I can see your error message is saying `Enter Discount in Integers` but then after that you try to cast discount to double. What do you intend to do here?

Comment: Well I want the users to enter integers. But i modify discount later on involving double values.

Comment: Do you mean `temp` value is reset to 0 after `ValidateDiscount` block is executed?

Comment: No, temp remains same. Discount is set to 0

Comment: Passing `Discount` to the `ValidateDiscount` method shouldn't modify `Discount` field, a function can only modify a parameter field if used as `out` or `ref` as seen in `TryParse` method. Put a breakpoint on the line where `Discount = temp` then step through the lines and see which line  modifies the `Discount` value. From the codes, I can't see any code that can modify it.